# Pass property to component as variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have parent component as below:

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import Header from "./header"
import "./layout.css"
import TopBar from "./topbar"
import Bottom from "./bottom"

const Layout = ({ children, isMobile = false }) => {
  const mainStyle = !isMobile ? ".main-desktop" : ".main-mobile"
  //children.isMobile = isMobile

  return (
    <>
      <Header siteTitle={'MAIN TITLE'}
        moto={'SLOGAN.'}
        isMobile={isMobile} />
      <TopBar isMobile={isMobile} />
      <div
        style={{
          margin: `0 auto 0 auto`,
          minHeight: `50%`,
          padding: `0 1.0875rem 1.45rem`,
          paddingLeft: "90px"
        }}
      >
        <main className={mainStyle}>{children}</main>
        <br />
        <br />
      </div>
      <Bottom isMobile={isMobile} />
    </>
  )
}

Layout.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
}

export default Layout
```

I have a child component as below:

import React from "react"
import SEO from "../components/seo"

```
const ContactUsPage = ({ isMobile = false }) => (
    <>
        <SEO title="Contact Us"
    </>
)

export default ContactUsPage
```

`ContactUsPage` is being called inside `Layout` by the Gatsby framework into `children` variable. Now, I want to pass `isMobile` property from `Layout`. I tried setting it directly but is giving error that object is not extensible.
What is the way and if possible, what is the correct way to set the property for variable components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this in two way, the Gatsby way and the React Context way:

**The Gatsby way:**

Gatsby allows you to pass a `state` prop to its `<Link/>` component.
The value of the state can then be retrieved from the page component (that automatically receives a `location` prop. See the [Gatsby documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-link/#pass-state-as-props-to-the-linked-page)

**The Context way:**

Create a React context that holds the `isMobile` value and a Component Provider:

```
export const MobileContext = React.createContext({ isMobile: false });

export MobileProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(false);

  // Define your logic to check if it is mobile or not

  const value = useMemo(() => ({ isMobile }), [isMobile]);

  return (
    <MobileContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </MobileContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

And wrap your layout with that.

Then you can access the context value on all Layout children (and their children too) with `const { isMobile } = useContext(MobileContext);`.
Check the [React context documentation](https://it.reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Answer (score 0):

In return in the parent component:

```
<ContactUsPage isMobile={isMobile} />
```

And inside `ContactUsPage` component:

```
const ContactUsPage = ({ isMobile }) => {
  return (
    <div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: In `Layout`, it is not known when `ContactUsPage` will be called and it is coming from `children` variable.